Google Sheets Weighted Average with multiple values and weights, have it ignore a blank cell
I'm creating a gradebook that has two grade categories, minor (40%) and major (60%), but within each category an assignment can carry a weight of 0.0-1.0. Each assignment has a max point score of 100. I've used the weighted average formula but it throws an error if a grade is not inputted yet. I've tried different formulas including filter, isnumber but I can't seem to make it work. I'm wanting the students weighted average to be calculated even if they have not completed the assignment (here's where the cell would be blank). Any help would be appreciated.
Screentshot
I've tried:
=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(C8:H8,C3:H3,C4:H4,C5:H5)
-this throws an error because of the empty cells of grades not input yet
=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(FILTER(C9:H9,ISNUMBER(C9:H9)),C3:H3,C4:H4,C5:H5)
-this throws an error saying mismatched range size
